# Where to store settings for C command line apps and bash scripts?

Tags: c, bash, command-line, nsuserdefaults

This may be an obvious question but I can't find a definitive answer.

When making a command line utility in C or when writing bash scrips where can I save values for later reference?

What I'm looking for is something similar to `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: "where" - in a file like `~/.my_app`.

Comment: So the norm is a hidden folder in the home directory?

Comment: Not necessary, but one example. It can be also `./my_app`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `bash` setup, the shell invocation normally reads `/etc/profile`, and the private equivalent `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`, upon startup.  So look at these files and make the appropriate modifications.  If possible, I suggest making a backup of these files prior to making any changes.

Be aware that the `/etc/profile` file will generally provide global settings while, if an equivalent file exists in your home directory, that file may override the global settings.

If you wish to add or modify environment variables *on the fly*, try ...

a. adding the following code to the end of your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` file

```
   if [ -e ./.bashadd ]
   then
        source ./.bashadd
   fi
```

b. append additions or modifications to the file `./.bashadd` *on the fly* (NOTE: you'll have to handle this within your program)

```
   echo export NAME=John >> ./.bashadd
```

c. at login, when you invoke `bash` or when you source your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` file, the environment variables will be available

Test:

```
[shell ~]$ echo export NAME=John >> ./.bashadd
[shell ~]$ source ./.bashrc
[shell ~]$ echo $NAME
John
[shell ~]$
```

Admittedly, not an ideal solution.  And I would suggest doing this only in your local environment and not globally (i.e. not with `/etc/profile`)

Comment: I already have a .bash_profile set up but I'm writing scripts that need to modify values on the fly and persistently save them.

Comment: Thanks this is a good solution. Is there any way of telling if a variable has already been defined.

Comment: `if [ -z "$YOUR_ENV_VAR" ];` will return true if a variable is the empty string or unset.